# UseSelector undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

Throws an error `undefined is not a function (near '...(0,react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useSelector)(state => state.files).map...')`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXGdj.png)
I wrap it in a function - the error is also similar, tell me what I wrote wrong?

File list

```
import React from 'react';
import './fileList.css'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import File from "./File/File";

const FileList = () => {
   const files = useSelector((state) => state.files.files).map((file) => <File key={file.id} file={file}/>)

return (
    <div className="container">
    <div className='filelist'>
        <div className="filelist__header">
            <div className="filelist__name">name</div>
            <div className="filelist__date">data</div>
            <div className="filelist__size">size</div>
        </div>
        {files}
    </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

export default FileList;

File

```
 import React from 'react';
import './file.css'
import dirLogo from '../../../../assets/img/dir.svg'
import fileLogo from '../../../../assets/img/file.svg'

const File = ({file}) => {

    return (
    <div className='file'>
        <img src={file.type === 'dir' ? dirLogo : fileLogo} alt="" className="file__img"/>
        <div className="file__name">{file.name}</div>
        <div className="file__date">{file.date.slice(0,10)}</div>
        <div className="file__size">{file.size}</div>
    </div>
);
```

};

export default File;

Comment: Have you definitely imported useSelector?

Comment: look you import useSelector correctly from `react-redux` and use `?` after this line `useSelector((state) => state.files)?.map(() => )

Comment: Yes, import {useSelector} from "react-redux", I thought it was the version, but I reinstalled it and it didn't help

Comment: can you post the whole other codes? including the import and stuff

Comment: @IamL i was update

Comment: are you sure `react-redux` is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the file like the following? Thanks!

```js
import React from 'react';
import './fileList.css'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import File from "./File/File";

const FileList = () => {
   const files = useSelector((state) => state.files.files);

return (
    <div className="container">
    <div className='filelist'>
        <div className="filelist__header">
            <div className="filelist__name">name</div>
            <div className="filelist__date">data</div>
            <div className="filelist__size">size</div>
        </div>
        {files?.map(eachFile => <File key={eachFile.id} file={eachFile}/>) ?? ""}
    </div>
    </div>
);

export default FileList
```

Comment: So it is than error:  Module parse failed: Unexpected token (61:21)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       columnNumber: 13
|     }
>   }, "size")), files?.map(function (eachFile) {
|     return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(File, {
|       key: eachFile.id,

Comment: Can u share snippet of your redux store file, your reducer files and package.json file...